# How to connect to a postgres cluster with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Is it at all possible to connect to a cluster?

Suppose I have a connection string such as,

```
postgresql://10.50.100.120:5432,10.50.100.121:5432/mydb
```

I've looked everywhere online, but couldn't find an answer. The closest I found was [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2308) issue and [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1470) one, but they didn't answer my question.

What are my options here?

Edit

Config:

```
{
            user: 'my_username',
            password: 'my_password',
            port: 5432,
            database: 'mydb',
            host: '10.50.100.120, 10.50.100.121',
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 10.50.100.120, 10.50.100.121
```

With Java, I can just point to this connection string with a `jdbc` prefix and it works fine. But how can I do this with Node? I'm not using `node-postgres`, I'm just using `pg`

Comment: Presumably you've tried the obvious thing and received an error or unexpected outcome - could you include that in the question to make it more searchable?

Comment: From a missing pg_hba or firewall entry to an alien invasion it can be anything :-D Jokes aside, if there is an error message, post it here and most certainly you'd get an answer. Cheers

Comment: I've updated the OP

Comment: "*What are my options here?*" - you already found the relevant issues. Go fix them in the library yourself if you need this, or work around them, or parse the string yourself and use only a single host. "*I'm not using `node-postgres`, I'm just using `pg`*" - [it is one and the same](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg).